# Orientation not updating after pop segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uiinterfaceorientation

## My setup

I have a `UICollectionViewController` which displays **2 columns in Portrait** and **3 Columns in Landscape**, Like So :

[image: Portrait Orientation] . . . .  [image: Landscape Orientation]

I am using this code to trigger a layout refresh on rotation :

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints
{
    [super updateViewConstraints];
    [[self.collectionView collectionViewLayout] invalidateLayout];
}
```

Everything is working fine, **But...**

## The issue

**1.** I am viewing the collectionView in Portrait :

[image: Portrait Orientation]

Everythings fine.

**2.** I click on one of the cells to go to a detail view, which also supports both orientations. Then on the detail view, I **switch the orientation to landscape**. Still good.

**3.** Still in Landscape, I now tap `< back` to come back to the collectionView,  and then this is what I see :

[image: The error]  OOPS!

I have absolutely no idea what is the cause of this. Searching on SO and Google didn't turn up anything.

## What I've Tried

I tried implementing this method in the collectionVC.m file :

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
   [super blahblah];
   [[self.collectionView collectionViewLayout] invalidateLayout];
}
```

Although it gets called when even I am on the detailView, it doesn't solve the issue.

## Notes :

1. I am not implementing any of those should/will/did methods related to orientation except the two I posted above.
2. One thing I noticed is that the collectionView is switching to a 2 column layout nd all. It seems like its the view bounds that is getting mixed up.

[image: Potato] Sorry for the long post. Here's a potato.

So Any thoughts on what is going wrong??

**Update** : I grabbed a [screenshot of the UI hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaYTP.png), might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1066762/ismail)'s [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34740122/3894781), which set me on the right path and I figured it out finally:

Upon careful observation of the code, I made some observations :

Firstly, the `UICollectionViewController` is properly adjusting to the rotation, it's `viewWillTransitionToSize:` and `updateViewConstraints` are getting called right on cue. The 3 column/2 column switch is also happening properly and all the required datasource methods are getting called.

**So Its not the CollectionViewController**

Then I took a closer look at the view hierarchy *(Image link at the end of my question)*.
Interestingly, the tabBar Controller still thinks its in portrait while everything above and below it has switched to landscape. The tab bar and all is still at portrait width.

<strike>So I just added this in the `CollectionViewController`'s `viewDidAppear` method :</strike>

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.tabBarController.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Even Better, I subclassed the TabBar controller and added this:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
}
```

**And that did the trick!**

I still have no idea why this is happening. So I will be investing and will update my answer when I find out more.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are facing is the rotation did happen when the collection viewController is not the visible one. so both `updateViewConstraints` and `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` will not get called.

There is two possible solutations for this probelm.

You can observe the the change of orientation

```
 // in viewDidLoad
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationDidChange:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

 - (void)orientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
  {
       //TODO: resetup the layout itemSize, etc if your it depend on the collection bounds.
       // and make sure to do that after the rotation did happend(i.e  in viewWillAppear or orientationDidChange:)
      [[self.collectionView collectionViewLayout] invalidateLayout];
  }
```

you can invalidate the layout in `viewWillAppear` anyway

```
     -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated  
     {  
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];  
        //TODO: resetup the layout itemSize, etc if your it depend on the collection bounds.
       // and make sure to do that after the rotation did happend(i.e  in viewWillAppear or orientationDidChange:)
       [[self.collectionView collectionViewLayout] invalidateLayout];
     }
```

Comment: which one of them did you try?

Comment: 1. `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` is getting called even when view is not visible. Already tried that.

Comment: 2. Also already tried invalidate in viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear. no effect.

Comment: Would you try `[self setNeedsLayout];` instead of invalidate layout in the both cases.please let me know what did you find out.

Comment: I just tried that, now the gap between the cells is gone, but still the same problem.

Comment: Would you provide some code about how you setup you layout configrations (i.e. itemSize and spacing). 
Please make sure to update these values just before calling invalidate layout evertime(if these values depends on the collection view bounds).
Please check my updated answer.